# x509 Errors when running docker build on corporate LAN

Tags: docker

This question applies specifically to Docker Desktop for Mac.

Our corporate network inserts an intermediate certificate in all SSL requests.  When I run `docker build` while connected to the network, this results in errors like:

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to authorize: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to fetch anonymous token: Get "https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Aamazon%2Faws-cli%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I've tried adding a bundle that includes our intermediate certs to `~/.docker/certs.d/auth.docker.io:443/ca.crt` but this didn't resolve the problem.  I've tried several variations of the `auth.docker.io:443` directory naming.

Were I on a Linux machine, I would append the certs to `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt` per the [dockerd documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#running-a-docker-daemon-behind-an-https_proxy) but that's not something that exists on Mac.  As I understand it, Docker for Mac *should* be importing any certs that are in my keychain, but the behavior I am seeing indicates otherwise.  I'm kind of at a loss what else to try besides disabling SSL verification entirely, but that is certainly not a preferred solution.

Answer (score 1):

For me adding registry to the insecure option did not work, so I go that way:

I used Chrome,

First, try to connect with your registry by a browser just type https:// address in the address bar and enter

Click on the "locker" icon next to the address and open the certificates chain  window as shown below

download all certificates which seem to be NOT trusted (one by one in the chain) by dragging big icons (marked by me on the picture) to the finder

Not trusted certs will appear in the chain with x in a red circle (see on the picture)

[image]

After that you should get the files in the finder with these certificates

add all of them to the system chain with the command:

```
sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain downloaded_cert_file
```

repeat command above for all cert files downloaded

next type [command key + space ] and search for Keychain Access

Open the keychain and go to System Certificates

Find the installed cert and double-click to open (it could still appear with red circle with "x" inside)

Hit the "Trust" dropdown arrow

Change "When Using This Certificate" from Use System Defaults to Always Trust (see on the picture below)

[image]

Exit window, you will be prompt for user and pass to save user-specific cert settings

Restart Docker daemon

Answer (score 0):

The [process for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/#add-custom-ca-certificates-server-side) is to update the macOS keychain:

```
sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain ca.crt
```

Once you've done that, there's an important note in the documentation:

> Note: You need to restart Docker Desktop after making any changes to the keychain or to the ~/.docker/certs.d directory in order for the changes to take effect.